# Changing an app's behavior how can one hide a checkout button depending on a number that is part of a string made up from a sum and a currency symbol?

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, dom-events, mutation-observers

I want to hide the checkout button when i select 6 options and that show a total of $260. So i select the total element and using java script i need that this button hide depending of total value
Before i try to hide with this code but some times it get 69 or another value  or show/hide the button alot of times randomly

```js
function hidenv() {

  var txt = document.querySelectorAll(".wapf-grand-total")[0].innerText;
  if (txt !== "$260") {document.querySelector("button").style.display = "none";
  }
        
}
```

there is the website

[link](https://demo2.msrwilo.com/producto/3-dias-1/)

[image: image demo code]

Comment: What about when the total is more than $260 ? Also your in function there is no code to display the button if the total decrease under $260

Comment: I think you need to put this `hideNav()` to where your values are changing. Every time you change something. It should get verified by `hideNav()`.

Comment: Is the calculation of the total amount done at client side? If yes, in how much control is the OP of the calculating script? If the OP actually can access and modify or hook into this script, the OP just needs to wait for the change of this total value (which should be just a number value without any currency attached to it). At this point the OP could notify another script which then takes care of the correct UI changes. Any other solution like utilizing a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver) should be the least favored option.

Comment: BTW ... the HTML markup is poorly written from a semantic point of view. It seems to be a soup of just `<div/>`s and `<span/>`s. That's not very nutritious.

Answer (score 1):

From the above given comment ...

> *"Is the calculation of the total amount done at client side? If yes, in how much control is the OP of the calculating script? If the OP actually can access and modify or hook into this script, the OP just needs to wait for the change of this total value (which should be just a number value without any currency attached to it). At this point the OP could notify another script which then takes care of the correct UI changes. Any other solution like utilizing a MutationObserver should be the least favored option."*

But in case the latter is the only option left, then a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) based solution might look similar to the next provided example code ...

```js
// closed 3rd party code one neither can access nor hook into.
//
function updateNumberValueAtBoundTarget({ currentTarget: { value } }) {
  const { outputNode, currencySymbol } = this;
  outputNode
    .value = [currencySymbol, value].join(' ');
}
function initializeThirdPartyCode() {
  document
    .querySelector('[type="number"]')
    .addEventListener(
      'input',
      updateNumberValueAtBoundTarget.bind({
        outputNode: document.querySelector('form output'),
        currencySymbol: '$',
      })
    );
}
initializeThirdPartyCode();

// possible approach ... `MutationObserver`
// - [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver]
//
function handleBehaviorOfBoundCheckoutTarget(mutationsList) { 
  const [ mutation ] = [...mutationsList];
  const {
    sourceNode,
    targetNode,
    lowerValidationValue = 10,
    upperValidationValue = 1000,
  } = this;

  if (
    (mutation.target === sourceNode) &&
    (mutation.type === 'childList') &&
    (mutation.addedNodes.length === 1)
  ) {
    const { nodeValue } = mutation.addedNodes?.[0] ?? '';

    // parse currency total into a number value ...
    const rawValue = parseFloat(nodeValue
      // ... by stripping any leading non digit characters ...
      .replace((/^\D+/), '')
      // ... and by stripping any trailing non digit characters.
      .replace((/\D+$/), '')
    );
    const isDisableCheckout = (
      !Number.isFinite(rawValue)
      || (rawValue < lowerValidationValue)
      || (rawValue > upperValidationValue)
    );
    targetNode.disabled = isDisableCheckout;
  }
}
function initialize() {
  const checkoutNode = document.querySelector('[type="submit"]');

  const observedNode = document.querySelector('.wapf-grand-total');
  const observerConfig = { childList: true/*, characterData: true */ };

  const observer = new MutationObserver(
    handleBehaviorOfBoundCheckoutTarget.bind({
      sourceNode: observedNode,
      targetNode: checkoutNode,
      lowerValidationValue: 0.01,
      upperValidationValue: 260,
    })
  );
  observer.observe(observedNode, observerConfig);
}
initialize();
```

```css
body { margin: -2px 0 0 0; }
form { position: relative; overflow: hidden; }
fieldset { margin: 0 0 10px 0; }
[type="submit"] { padding: 10px; float: right; margin-right: 10px; }
[type="number"] { padding: 5px; width 5em; }
label > span,
label > input { display: block; }
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Total</legend>
    <output class="wapf-grand-total">$ 0</output>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit" disabled>Checkout</button>
</form>

<label>
  <span>Simulation of 3rd party total calculation</span>
  <input type="number" min="0" max="100000" step="10" value="0"/>
</label>
```

Comment: @msrwilo ... Are there any questions left regarding the above approach?

Comment: @msrwilo ... At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score -1):

you can avoid rapid execution this way

```js
var cancelRapid ,timeGap = 500

function hidenv() {
  clearTimeout(cancelRapid)
  cancelRapid = setTimeout(function(){
    // code here
    console.log("triggered")    
  },timeGap)
}

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input",hidenv)
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```